# Почему ссылка (<a>) не центрируется по горизонтали и вертикали?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

```css
section { 
 margin-right: 30px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 5px;
 height: 200px;
 width: 330px;
}

.date {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #ddd;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

section .course {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 
}

section .course a {
 color: blue;
 text-decoration: none;
}
section .course a:hover {
 color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="date">
    25.03.2019 18:00 - 15.04.2019 21:20
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <a href="#">
      Курс
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что Ваш section .course по высоте равен высоте ссылки. Он не занимает (как Вам, очевидно, хотелось бы) всё оставшееся пространство в section. Чтобы это произошло, section тоже надо сделать flex, а section .course добавить flex-grow: 1

```css
section { 
 margin-right: 30px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 5px;
 height: 200px;
 width: 330px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.date {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #ddd;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

section .course {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

section .course a {
 color: blue;
 text-decoration: none;
}
section .course a:hover {
 color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="date">
    25.03.2019 18:00 - 15.04.2019 21:20
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <a href="#">
      Курс
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Долго пытался понять почему надо задать section display:flex и flex-direction:column, а .course задать flex-grow: 1, но так и не понял. Можете пожалуйста объяснить ?

Comment: Я нашел еще один способ: задать для .course свойство height: 159px (высота section - высота .date = 159.5px ~ 159px) и для .course a -  свойство width: 165px (половину от ширины контейнера)

Comment: @JustLearn, ну, в принципе, можно и фиксированную высоту задать, конечно, но это прошлый век - раз уж Вы флексы используете, так и пользуйтесь всеми их преимуществами

Comment: @JustLearn, flex-direction:column нужен для того, чтобы блоки внутри (как и сейчас) шли сверху вниз (иначе они выстроятся слева направо), а flex-grow: 1 для того и нужен, чтобы блок занимал всё оставшееся пространство. Причём независимо от того, какая высота у родителя. Если высота вдруг изменится, Вам не надо подгонять высоту внутреннего блока - он подстроится автоматически

Answer (score 0):

Задайте `.course` высоту.

```
section .course {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: при height: 100%; section .course вылезет за пределы section - Вы бы хоть потестили, прежде чем давать ответ